# Silverman AEC Theorem 7.4

Tags: modules, tensor-products, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

The theorem:

> Let $E_{1},E_{2}$ be elliptic curves and let $\ell\neq$char($K$) be a prime. Then then natural map
> $$\operatorname{Hom}(E_{1},E_{2})\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{\ell}\longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(T_{\ell}(E_{1}),T_{\ell}(E_2)),\quad \phi\mapsto\phi_\ell$$
> is injective.

Here $T_{\ell}(E_{i})$ is the Tate module of the elliptic curve ${E_{i}}$. I don't understand how the tensor product is taken. I know that $\operatorname{Hom}(E_{1},E_{2})$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. But in the theorem, is the tensor product taken as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules? If so why is it true that,
$$rank_{\mathbb{Z}} \operatorname{Hom}(E_{1},E_{2})=rank_{\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}}\operatorname{Hom}(E_1,E_2)\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$$
Is $\operatorname{Hom}(E_{1},E_{2})$ also a $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$-module? If so how.

Comment: Oof. Your displayed equation, which admittedly is quoted from Silverman III.7.5, is not true in the sense that the book claims. Yes, Silverman's proof of III.7.5 is flawed. (The flaw is known in some circles, but strangely Silverman hasn't fixed it yet, even though there was an opportunity to do so in the second edition of the book). The only correct and clearly written proof of this statement that I know of is in Mumford's Abelian Varieties book.

Comment: The Mumford reference is: Theorem 3 on page 164 of the Tata Institute edition of Mumford's book (page 177 in the original edition) corresponds to a correct statement and proof of Silverman III.7.4, and Corollary 1 of Mumford on the next page corresponds to a correct statement and proof of Silverman III.7.5.

Comment: @djao Alright,thanks for the reference!Also,I'm curious is this related to you:https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~djao/co690.2007/elliptic3.pdf. If so,the proof is so well-written with all the correct details!

Comment: Pretty sure that proof was written by Cam Zwarich as indicated on my site. It's the Mumford proof with the details written out.